# Which words of foreign origin kept a distinctive feminine?

Tags: loanwords, feminine

The feminine of **confidant** is **confidante**, probably due to the French origin of the word (*confident*, whose feminine is *confidente*). I wonder which other words of foreign origin commonly used in English have kept their original feminine?

*Edit:* so there may be entire categories of such words, of course, I should have thought of that. Do people have examples other from languages other than French, Italian and Latin? I was trying to think, for example, of a pair of such words of German origin, but can't find any.

Comment: Watch out for @Kosmo, he won't like you [calling them foreign words](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8463/how-english-can-you-get-closed) :)

Comment: I think this would include a large number of words that inflect for gender using suffixes like _-ess_, _-ette_, _-ine_, _-ina_, _-trix_. (_princess_, _ballerina_, _fiancee_, _abbess_, _duchess_)

Comment: This question should probably be a CW.

Comment: Kiam: Enlighten me, why a CW?

Comment: @mplungjan: Because the question is asking for examples; every answer would be equally acceptable, and there would not be a right answer.

Comment: If the combined list was exhaustive, why not?

Comment: @mplungian: have you read http://english.stackexchange.com/faq?  http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/ is a good place for discussing policy.

Comment: To be exhaustive, the answer should also include what reported in other questions. Still, every question would be equally valid.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: as evidenced by the lots of answers and examples provided, I don't believe this needed to be a CW

Comment: @FX_: I see only an answer.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: hence the irony

Comment: @FX_: I stand correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be lots...

French:

- *princess* (from Old French *princesse*) and *prince*; *countess*, *duchess*, *marquise*, *baroness*, and lots of other *-ess* words
- *doyenne* and *doyen*

Italian:

- *ballerina* (although you don't see *ballerino* very often)
- *prima donna* (and rarely *primo uomo*)

Latin:

- *victrix*  and *victor*
- *aviatrix* and *aviator* (although we seldom use these Latin suffixes anymore)

Comment: Afrikaans: Komponiste, 
Dutch: Componiste

Comment: @mplungjan: but is Komponiste (or Componiste) used in English?

Comment: Nope, hence a comment on an answer containing Italian and Latin :)

Comment: @mplungjan: fair enough!

Comment: @mplungjan - I submitted my answer before FX_'s edit ;) And these are all words that English has assimilated and anglicised in pronunciation.